# Connect Manager not able to install

Tags: email, installation, magento-connect, permissions

I've recently move my Magento shop from one server to another, and since then I haven't had else but problems. I can't blame the host because they are running on professional servers with CentOS, where I used to run it from a Mac Mini with MAMP Pro installed.

But the system doesn't send out mails, so I figured I would try to install the ASchroder SMTP Pro plugin for sending out mails through SMTP instead. But I can't install it from the Magento Connect Manager.

When I paste the install-path to the downloader, and press 'Install' it's only output is:

> Connection Error try again later.

I've looked at my settings, file permissions and such, but nothing has worked so far. My Magento Connect Manager settings is as following:

[image: My settings for Magento Connect Manager]

As you can see, I can't select Local Filesystem.

Can anybody help me with either the mail sending problems or the Connect Manager installation problems?

Comment: Making Downloader folder writable to 777 will work

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you're entering the correct FTP details by trying to access the server using an FTP client like FileZilla/SmartFTP etc.

If you are, make sure that you are using the correct key from MagentoConnect:

`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/ASchroder_SMTPPro`

Alternately, as a temporary solution, you can download the source files directly off of MagentoConnect using this tool:

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Simply paste the key into the textarea, then install onto your file server via FTP client.

Comment: 1) FTP details are correct
2) Downloading and uploading the file generates this error: Error moving uploaded file

Comment: Check your folder permissions on the server, seems to be the problem. Right click on the folders and make sure that you have the correct permissions (i.e read/write), you may want to contact your host

Answer (score 1):

The `Local Filesystem` option is disabled if the method `Maged_Controller::isWritable` returns false.
See `Maged_Controller::settingsAction()`:

```
$fs_disabled =! $this->isWritable();
```

Make your `downloader` folder writable and it should work.

If the problem persists see what the `isWritable` method looks like and what conditions have to be met.

**[EDIT]**
As for the error mentioned in the comments

> Warning: include(DOMDocument.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in ...

[you need to install the php-xml module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php)

Comment: Making the downloader-folder writeable, makes the Local Filesystem selectable again, but when I change the settings and save them, they changes doesn't get saved.

Comment: @ThomasUrupMichaelsen. Anything in var/log ?

Comment: 2014-02-06T09:25:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(DOMDocument.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/web001/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

2014-02-06T09:25:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'DOMDocument.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/web001/www/downloader/lib:/home/web001/www/app/code/local:/home/web001/www/app/code/community:/home/web001/www/app/code/core:/home/web001/www/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /home/web001/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: @ThomasUrupMichaelsen. See my update.

Comment: Already done - but doesn't change much for me.

Comment: @ThomasUrupMichaelsen. I'm out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: I haven't had these problems before, so it's also quite new to me, and I'm already tearing out hairs because of it. :@ But thanks for trying